# Partial fraction decomposition of the given equation

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I do the partial fraction decomposition for $$\frac{z}{z^2+1}$$

This is in terms of complex analysis. I know how to do this in terms of  $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$, but not sure what to do about it when the numerator is z instead of 1.

FYI, I know that $z^2+1 = (z+i)(z-i)$, so the above can be re-expressed as $$\frac{z}{z^2+1}= \frac{z}{(z+i)(z-i)}$$

Answer (score 2):

You know:
$$
\frac{z}{z^{2}+1}=\frac{z}{(z+i)(z-i)}=\frac{a}{z+i}+\frac{b}{z-i}
$$

so we multiply both sides by $z^2+1$ and get:
$$
a(z-i)+b(z+i)=z
$$

Set $z=i$ to solve for $b$ and $z=-i$ to solve for a and you get:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z+i}+\frac{1}{z-i}\right)
$$

($a=b=\frac{1}{2}$)

Answer (score 0):

You know that $\frac z{z^2+1}$ can be written as$$\frac a{z+i}+\frac b{z-i}=\frac{(a+b)z+i(-a+b)}{z^2+1}.$$So, solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a+b=1\\-a+b=0.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: If you are restricted to real numbers, then there is NO simpler "partial fractions"